# I Want Load My JSON URL Data to My Android App

Tags: android, json

Simply, I Want Get My JSON Data from URL.

For know I am come from iOS, :) in iOS it's very easy to get and store into `nsdictionary` then I can get any row with just the column name. But in Android, I don't know.

I see some ex, for get data from url. And it's works fine with me. The problem is how I Can `onItemClick` to pass the current row clicked to `showActivity`?

***Here's what I want to do***

1 - load JSON Data from URL

2 - put them into `ListView`

3 - send clicked row Data on `listView` to to `showActivity`

For know I don't want just `Title` and I want all rows of JSON but for clicked row, because there another rows like views and length for more here the JSON Data column.

```
id - title - views - length
```

And thanks in advance.

Comment: You are half way there. You are asking yourself the right questions. I'm sure if you search each one of them, you'll find lots of stackoverflow answers for each. Then you can just combine all the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the JSON as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604752/android-parse-json-from-url-and-store-it) but instead of writing it to a file once you have your `JSONArray` or `JSONObject` just hold in the activity as a variable. From your question I gather it's most likely a JSONArray that will be downloaded so there is no reason you can't keep this array in a `JSONArray` object in your activity and retrieve the JSON based on the index number of the item clicked.

If your JSON is too large to hold in memory then you can use a file to page your JSON with a streaming API like Jackson.

If you need to preserve your JSON on orientation change then you can just call `toString` and get a string which you can put in your outgoing bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you get a JSONObject from request, but it's not a Parcelable object, so you can't send it to another activity by intent.

I think you can transform the JSONObject to String by call it's function named 'toString()', send it, and then recreate it in another activity.